# Bitname Gitlab backup and restore without stopping server

Tags: backup, gitlab, restore, bitnami

Currently we are doing the process of backup and restore as explained below:

https://docs.bitnami.com/google/apps/gitlab/#how-to-create-a-full-backup-of-gitlab

This requires stopping the server, specially for taking the backup.

Is it possible to do backup and restore without stopping the server? How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The risk of not stopping the server is that there's the risk that not all the changes in, for example, the Database, are written to disk correctly. Therefore, you could end up in an unstable state. If you really want to try, you can follow the exact procedure without the `/opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh stop` part. The thing is, when restoring the server, you may have to execute `/opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart`.

In any case, I do not recommend you to try it.

Comment: the problem is that our data is almost 70 GB (increasing always) and it is taking almost 3 hours to take the backup. So, our server is stopped for almost 3 hours.

Comment: I suppose you can also try to do a `mysqldump` and save it to a file. I think that the rest of the process could be moved without stopping.

Comment: Can you please explain this in more detail.